# Main activity is not present in android studio

Tags: java, android

I would like some help/advice on an issue I have involving Android Studio.I'm using android studio and the java language to code however, whenever I try to create a bottom navigation activity in my project only the UI folder is present however the main activity isn't present on the left hand project menu and I was hoping you could help me with this issue, just to make you aware that the problem is not because of any errors in my code and I have tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, it also isnt in the UI folder.The clip i have attached to this email will display the issue.Thank you in advance.

Yours sincerely, UltraSavageGamer

[my project menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WESYE.png)

[adding bottom navigation activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0MJ3.png)

[bottom navigation activity added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Rk9z.png)

[main activity not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKlpe.png)

Comment: can you check the "ui" package? the main activity should be there

Comment: i checked and it is not there thank you

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure you can see the MainActivity.java in your explore folder (where you save your project). If it existes, you can change the view of Android Studio to see it like the picture below:
[image]

Change the view mode to "project files" or sth else to look for your MainActivity.

Comment: thanks a lot however I cant see the main activity and still couldn't find it after changing the view mode but thanks anyway

Comment: Did you see the file on  project saved path? like /home/Desktop/SkypeClone3/main/MainActivity.java?

Comment: So I suggest you just create a new java class instead of new activity, then creates a new layout under res folder, after that link between the two file by "R.findViewById".